# how to revoke x.509 certificates?

Tags: ssl, certificates

I recently accepted some x.509 certificates on my Ubuntu 16.04 because of open-connect and I wonder how can I delete or revoke them on my system. My problem is I have no idea what were the details of those certificates and some how I need to sort them by time to find last ones and then delete them.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you want to revoke client certificates on a web server like apache?

If so you need a Certification Recovation list.

Create with openssl a revoke  file:

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf \
      -gencrl -out myserver.crl.pem
```

Then, install that file in apache config.